# Google Maps API V3 - Polygon SMOOTHED edges

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon, curve, smoothing

Is it possible to smooth the lines/edges for a polygon?  It's currently very sharp and angular and it would be great if those angles actually had curvature to them.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm in need of this too so let me know if you found a good way to do it. I would assume you have to pass an array of points (vertices of the polygon that was mapped) to a curve smoothing/fitting algorithm which would then generate a new set of points (more than the original set most likely) that you can display on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Add additional points into your polygon.  The more points that are plotted, the more gradual the curve will be.

Comment: But then you have to drag each added point to its new location manually. Better to use some algorithm (would be nice if Maps API had one built in).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a smoothing algorithm based on bSpline that worked for me on Android inspired by https://johan.karlsteen.com/2011/07/30/improving-google-maps-polygons-with-b-splines/

```
 public List<LatLng> bspline(List<LatLng> poly) {

        if (poly.get(0).latitude != poly.get(poly.size()-1).latitude || poly.get(0).longitude != poly.get(poly.size()-1).longitude){
            poly.add(new LatLng(poly.get(0).latitude,poly.get(0).longitude));
        }
        else{
            poly.remove(poly.size()-1);
        }
        poly.add(0,new LatLng(poly.get(poly.size()-1).latitude,poly.get(poly.size()-1).longitude));
        poly.add(new LatLng(poly.get(1).latitude,poly.get(1).longitude));

        Double[] lats = new Double[poly.size()];
        Double[] lons = new Double[poly.size()];

        for (int i=0;i<poly.size();i++){
            lats[i] = poly.get(i).latitude;
            lons[i] = poly.get(i).longitude;
        }

        double ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, dx, dy, lat, lon;
        float t;
        int i;
        List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
        // For every point
        for (i = 2; i < lats.length - 2; i++) {
            for (t = 0; t < 1; t += 0.2) {
                ax = (-lats[i - 2] + 3 * lats[i - 1] - 3 * lats[i] + lats[i + 1]) / 6;
                ay = (-lons[i - 2] + 3 * lons[i - 1] - 3 * lons[i] + lons[i + 1]) / 6;
                bx = (lats[i - 2] - 2 * lats[i - 1] + lats[i]) / 2;
                by = (lons[i - 2] - 2 * lons[i - 1] + lons[i]) / 2;
                cx = (-lats[i - 2] + lats[i]) / 2;
                cy = (-lons[i - 2] + lons[i]) / 2;
                dx = (lats[i - 2] + 4 * lats[i - 1] + lats[i]) / 6;
                dy = (lons[i - 2] + 4 * lons[i - 1] + lons[i]) / 6;
                lat = ax * Math.pow(t + 0.1, 3) + bx * Math.pow(t + 0.1, 2) + cx * (t + 0.1) + dx;
                lon = ay * Math.pow(t + 0.1, 3) + by * Math.pow(t + 0.1, 2) + cy * (t + 0.1) + dy;
                points.add(new LatLng(lat, lon));
            }
        }
        return points;

    }
```